# Where does TEMPORARY file system storage store with chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, fileserver, html5-filesystem

I am using file system API to save some text into TEMPORARY storage. I use the webkitRequestFileSystem and window.Temporary option, but I don't know where it is stored?